# UE4 Procedural Planet Design

Tags: procedural-generation, savegame, blueprints

I am building a game that requires a full planet but it would be too complicated to create it as one mesh, so I decided that I will use procedural generation to create the (partially) editable landscape, rocks, trees, caves, etc. I was wondering on what server-side a procedural planet is generated? For example, is it generated when the player first plays the game, and is it the same for every player? Or is it completely rebuilt each time the player enters the game? If the answer is the latter, is there any way to somehow save the planet and make it into one map for everybody using the game and not change if they reload the game? If possible, I would strongly prefer any answers in Blueprints rather than C++. FYI: I haven't started building the game yet and am still researching my options for how to create the world. I didn't find much about saving the character's location anywhere so far.

Comment: This can vary substantially from game to game. How do you want it to work in your game? Your game, your universe, your rules. How have you tried making it so far, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: I was planning to have one planet that is fully roamable, with a little bit less gravity than earth but a similar terrain style and atmosphere but it would've been too heavy on the engine to render it all beforehand. I haven't started creating it yet, as I thought I would have a different blueprint in order to make it save.

Comment: Can players modify the planet in any way?

Comment: Some small portions of the map should be alterable (eg: some specific cave walls can be mined) but they'll mostly be separate actors like rocks and trees. This leads to another question, could the trees and rocks be procedurally generated along with the terrain?

Comment: Why not? It's your game. Whatever you feel is worthwhile to spend time building, you can build. Regarding your main question: typically something like this is done via a "seed", an input to your procedural generator that sets the pattern of pseudorandom numbers it generates. If you store and re-use the same seed, you don't have to generate or save the whole planet. When the player returns to an area, you can re-generate it from the seed and get the same result. That way you only need to store the seed and any changes the player made. Minecraft works this way.

Comment: With that in mind, can you edit your question to focus on the first concrete step in implementing your design that you need our help solving? Right now the question isn't very clear, but if you can narrow it down to one focused problem, you'll tend to get better answers, faster.

Comment: Ok thanks, how do I save the changes that the player makes? And is it possible to make the original spawn seed for every game the same? Would each person's copy of the game have the same map?

Comment: You don't need to ask "would it work like this" - it's your game. You choose the way it works. If you need help making it work the way you want, edit your question to focus on that issue.

Comment: It's still unclear to me what you've done or researched so far to try to build your planet, and what one, single step you need help with next. Please edit your post to focus on one narrow question, as in its current form it's at risk of being put on hold as too broad to answer.